# Resnet50 Transfer Learning with tensorflow.keras version 2.4+

Tags: machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning, resnet

I have a model architecture based on a resnet50 that needs to be retrained regularly. It worked for years. It is running on tensorflow version 1.9 and keras 2.3.1. Now I bought a new computer with a RTX 3070 - which means I have to use tensorflow 2.4 or higher in order to make use of the GPU. I installed tensorflow 2.5 together with the relevant Cuda 11.2 and cudnn 8.1, manually copied some files - and the model is indeed running on GPU. However, when I freeze layers of the base model, I get completely different results as compared to when I run it on my old computer. For example: For two warm-up epochs with all layers of the resnet50 frozen, I get more than 50 percent accuracy on my old computer - but only 7.5 on the new one.
I am aware of the problems with BatchNormalization layers and followed the tutorial (or instruction) here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

how to solve the issue (as you can see in the code below). I also tried to downgrade tensorflow to 2.4, reinstalled Anaconda and set everything up from scratch, etc. - but nothing works.
To compare the two architectures and in order make sure that no other reason could be responsible for the discrepancy, I copied the entire data on an external hard drive - and only adjusted the imports from keras to tensorflow.keras (together with some other small alterations necessary to use tensorflow.keras, i.e. using fit instead of fit_generator, etc.). Could someone look at the code for the tensorflow.keras model (second code block from top) - and tell me where I go wrong.

Here is the code for the model in keras (which works perfectly):

```
# =============================================================================
# Build model
# =============================================================================

from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.models import  Model
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Input, \
    AveragePooling2D
from keras import initializers
from keras import optimizers

in_shape = (224,224,3) # Shape of input images

n_classes = 26 # Number of classes

dor = 0.3 # Dropout rate

learning_rate = 5e-5

optim = optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)

base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', \
                      input_shape=in_shape)

inp = Input(shape=in_shape)
x = base_model(inp)
x = AveragePooling2D((7, 7), name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(dor)(x)
x = Dense(2048, \
              kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(), \
              bias_initializer=initializers.ones(), \
              activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(n_classes, kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(), \
          bias_initializer=initializers.ones(), activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inp, x)

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, \
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# =============================================================================
# Train model
# =============================================================================

# Warm up phase
for layer in model.layers[1].layers:
  layer.trainable =  False

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                              validation_data=val_generator,
                              epochs=warm_up_epochs,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_spe, 
                              validation_steps=val_spe,
                              verbose=1)
```

The output is:

[image]

And here is the code for the tensorflow.keras model (which does NOT work):

```
# =============================================================================
# Build model
# =============================================================================

from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.models import  Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout, Input, \
    AveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers

in_shape = (224,224,3) # Shape of input images

n_classes = 26 # Number of classes

dor = 0.3 # Dropout rate

learning_rate = 5e-5

optim = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate)

# resnet50, pretrained on Imagenet
base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', \
                      input_shape=in_shape)

inp = Input(shape=in_shape)
x = base_model(inp, training=False)
x = AveragePooling2D((7, 7), name='avg_pool')(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dropout(dor)(x)
x = Dense(2048, \
              kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(), \
              bias_initializer=initializers.ones(), \
              activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(n_classes, kernel_initializer=initializers.he_normal(), \
          bias_initializer=initializers.ones(), activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(inp, x)

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, \
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

# =============================================================================
# Train model
# =============================================================================

# Warm up phase
for layer in model.layers[1].layers:
  layer.trainable =  False

model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optim, \
              metrics=('accuracy'))

model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_generator,
                    validation_data=val_generator,
                    epochs=warm_up_epochs,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_spe, 
                    validation_steps=val_spe,
                    verbose=1)
```

The output is:

[image]

the striking thing is: When I do NOT freeze layer, the performance of the tensorflow.keras model is comparable to the one of the keras model. As I said, I do not know where I gor wrong here. Any help is appreciated,
Thank you very much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have actually (after a few days of despair and getting started in PyTorch due to the frustration) just now found a hack to solve this behavior. The problem is that the official tensorflow post about finetuning models:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning

is actually wrong - at least for tensorflow version 2.5 (but I would assume that it is probably from 2.4 upwards).
In the link above it is explained in quite some detail why you, when you build the model, have to set the parameter "training" to False, i.e. in the above code in the line:

```
x = base_model(inp, training=False)
```

If you do NOT do that - and then only set the non batch_normalization layers to False when freezing layers, it all works. I.e. what I did was:

```
# Warm up phase
for layer in model.layers[1].layers:
  if '_bn' not in layer.name:
     layer.trainable =  False
```

after checking the names of the layers in resnet50 - where each BatchNormalization layer name ends with '_bn'.

If you exclude the BatchNormalization layers from freezing (like above) AND leave the training parameter set to False, it still does not work.
This is of course only a quick and dirty hack - and maybe there is a better solution. If you know of one, please let me know. But for the moment at least this works, also with freezing only some layers, etc.